# How to change the value of a boolean when a JButton is pressed

Tags: java, swing, boolean, jbutton, actionlistener

My question states it all.

Here is my code:

```
                fullscreen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        MainMenu.isFullscreen = true;
                    }
                });
```

Where fullscreen is a JButton.

And then in my Screen class:

if(mm.isFullscreen) {

```
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(this);

        repaint();
    }
```

With mm being a deceleration of MainMenu. When mm.isFullscreen is false the Screen is its normal size.

I think I read somewhere that ActionListeners can't change the value of something outside the ActionListener...?

edit:

I have fixed the isue thanks for the help but this is new code:

In the screen class:

public void setFullscreen() {

```
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(this);

    repaint();
}
```

In the mainMenu class:

fullscreen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

```
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    if(isFullscreen) {

                            isFullscreen = false;
                        }


                        if(!isFullscreen) {

                            isFullscreen = true;

                            screen.setFullScreen();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I dont see the issue. An ActionListener can access variables like every other class.

Comment: Have you tested if your boolean is actually changing? Changes to variables may not be seen on another thread if your code is not thread safe.

Comment: well it seams very literal that it would change.

Comment: i have the same exact code for a different jbutton called quit except that quit does System.exit(). if the quit button can exicute its code successfully why cant the fullscreen button?

Comment: my hypothesis is that it is set to true but the code in the screen class is executed at the begining of runtime therfor even though isFullscreen is now true that code is useless.

Answer (score 0):

When setting `isFullscreen = false;` you are not changing the state of full screen window!

You may use `GraphicsDevice#setFullScreenWindow(null);` to set it back to windowed mode.